# How to set a global retry limit in sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I would like to configure a global retry limit in Sidekiq to limit the number of retries. By default Sidekiq [limits the number of retries to 25](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling) but I want to set it lower for all Workers to prevent the long default maximum retry period if the limit is not explicitly specified on the Worker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Sidekiq.default_worker_options['retry'] = 10
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#workers

Comment: Apart from @mike-perham being the library's author and doing what he says, it probably makes sense to mutate just the key `retry`, as is stated here, instead of clobbering the entire hash.

Comment: now called default_job_options https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/main/Changes.md#642

Answer (score 14):

You can also configure in your **sidekiq.yml**

```rb
:max_retries: 10
:queues:
  - queue_1
  - queue_2
```

Refer doc [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#automatic-job-retry)

Answer (score 3):

This value is being [stored in `options`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/ad38803a8c05df05d3eec73ea039876f4432610a/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb#L70) and (AFAIK) has no nifty setter for it, so here you go:

```
Sidekiq.options[:max_retries] = 5
```

It might be set for `RetryJobs` in the middleware initializer [as well](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/dc3c69065bfe003bd12677ff5439429c01850cff/Changes.md#2131).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Sidekiq.default_worker_options` in your initializer. So to set a lower limit it'd be

```
Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { retry: 5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently working on setting this up to limit the amount of error noise created by our staging environments (for the sake of trying to stay well below our error handling service limits). It seems that the key is now `max_retries` when changing the amount, and `retry` is a boolean for whether it should retry at all or go right to the "Dead" queue.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#automatic-job-retry

This is what it looks for me in my Sidekiq config file:

```
if Rails.env.staging?
  Sidekiq.default_worker_options['max_retries'] = 5
end
```

UPDATE: could have been my own confusion, but for some reason, `default_worker_options` did not seem to be working consistently for me. I ended up changing it to this and it worked as I hoped. Failed jobs went straight to the `Dead` queue:

```
Sidekiq.options[:max_retries] = 0
```